# MongoDB - Querying a nested boolean field

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following mongoclient query:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("test-db");
hosts = db.getCollection("test-collection")
db.hosts.aggregate([
    {$match: {"ip_str": {$in: ["52.217.105.116"]}}}
]);
```

Which outputs this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "ip_str" : "52.217.105.116",
    "data" : [
        {"ssl" : {"cert" : {"expired" : "False"}}}
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to build the query so it returns a boolean `True` or `False` depending on the value of the `ssl.cert.expired` field. I'm not quite sure how to do this though. I've had a look into the `$lookup` and `$where` operators, but am not overly familiar with querying nested objects in Mongo yet.

Comment: Is this output match your need? [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UQZmMBQSs_6)

Comment: yes is does! thank you. If you'd like to submit it ill accept the answer. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `data` is an array, in order to get the (first) element of the nested `expired`, you should work with `$arrayElemAt` and provide an index as 0 to indicate the first element.

```
{
  $project: {
    ip_str: 1,
    expired: {
      $arrayElemAt: [
        "$data.ssl.cert.expired",
        0
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playgound](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UQZmMBQSs_6)